Is it okay that the power LED blinks 8 to 9 times as soon as I press the power button and then stays on steadily? Motherboard: ASUS B460M-A
I recently got an Asus B460M-A. (The one that only supports 10th generation Intel). It worries me because as soon as I press the power button, the power LED flashes quickly 8-9 times (no video here), then the LED stays on for about 2 seconds and at the same time shows the first classic screen (The one that shows the CPU, Memory, or if the keyboard is connected or not), it quickly goes to the next screen where the ASUS logo appears and at the same time the LED turns off, half a second later the power LED turns on, Windows load and the LED remains stable. It doesn't turn off again. The speaker only emits the classic short beep that everything went well. There are no video glitches. Since I press the power button, my PC takes 6-7 seconds to display the Windows welcome screen. And everything seems to be working fine. Is it okay for the power LED to flash those 8-9 times as soon as I turn on the PC? Is it part of the Power On Self Test? Thanks in advance.

Your system isn’t even getting past POST. Verify the socket has zero pins. Verify all cables. Essentially you should boot with only the CPU and memory installed, you should be able to confirm the system boots, by the diagnostic capability of the motherboard

You should check what the blinks mean. It could indicated a failed cmos battery. As long as the system remains powered by the mains, the cmos won't lose data, but as soon as that goes out, your bios settings would be reset, which can lead to the time changing etc. wrong time can lead to problems loading anything with SSL.
